# write the name of all files in a directory, and their absolute path, to a csv file in bash

Tags: bash, csv

This is harder than I expected, but I have a folder with ~100 datasets in .csv format.

I would like to create a .csv file with the following fields:

- The first field is the file's name. e.g. `user_profile.csv`
- The second field is the file's absolute path, e.g. `/Users/yuqli/project/user_profile.csv`

I would like to do this with bash commands. But so far I have only be able to do :

```
ls >> out.csv
```

which will write all file names into a txt file... I see some people using a for loop, but manipulating lines in .csv file seems forbidding, and I don't know what to put inside the for loop...

Am I better off just using Python? Any help is appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: You *are* better off using Python. The easy answers will get the details (like files that have commas or newlines or quotes in their names) wrong.

Comment: `find "$PWD" -type f -printf '"%f","%p"\n'` is one of those simple-but-wrong answers, btw.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! I've spent hours exploring shell's capacities... solved with Python's `os` module.

Comment: Also nice answer! Thanks!

Comment: Unless you are also using the `csv` module, your solution is probably just as wrong as the `find` command mentioned above.

Comment: `/bin/ls *.csv >out.csv; sed 's/^\(.*\)$/\1,\/somepath\/before\/\1/' out.csv`  I tried with spaces and commas in the filenames, it works.  Each line has `filename,PATH/filename`

Comment: @Nic3500, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- different versions of `ls` behave differently. And I specified not just commas and spaces, but literal quotes as a case to test: `touch '"hello ,",cruel,", world.txt"'` to create a filename that exercises some of those pathological situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice of gurus above, I came up with this Python program that 1) extracts file names and 2) extract field names in each file. Any comments are welcomed. Thanks!

```
import os
import csv
info = {}    # store all information into a Python dictionary
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    with open(filename, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        row1 = next(reader)
        info[filename] = row1

path = os.getcwd()
header = 'field, dataset, path'
write_file = "output.csv"
with open(write_file, "w") as output:
    output.write(header + '\n')
    for key, value in info.items():
        for elem in value:
            curr_path = path + key
            line = '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(elem, key, curr_path)
            output.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: You really should be using `csv.writer()` on the output end; filenames that can't be substituted literally into a CSV string (that is, without quoting) will misbehave (in the same way as my `find -printf` example!) otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comment! What do you mean by "filenames that can't be substituted literally into a CSV string (that is, without quoting) "?  In the mean time I'll look into how to use csv.writer()...

Comment: See the example of a pathological case I gave in my most recent comment on the question -- if the name of the file that `touch` command creates is put into a CSV file without being correctly escaped first, pieces of it will be parsed by Excel or other CSV readers into separate columns.

Comment: (and that's not even as pathological as they get; check how your code behaves correctly after `touch $'two\nlines'` has been run to generate a name that has a newline in the middle of it, for example).

Comment: So the file is named as _hello ,",cruel,", world.txt_? I find it hard to parse the single / double quotes even as for human :)

Comment: Right -- that's the point of using libraries written by people closely following the CSV specification, so your code can do the right thing without you needing to puzzle it out yourself. :) -- same principle applies for why one should always, *always* use libraries to parse or generate JSON, XML, etc.

Comment: Note that bad filenames can happen without malicious intent -- the worst data loss event I saw in my career was caused by a bad pointer in a C library used by a Python script dumping memory that happened to include a whitespace-surrounded `*` into a buffer that was used to generate a filename (which a poorly-written shell script later tried to delete).